# List all files using firebase storage gives me 404 when trying to use getDownloadUrl

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to list files under a folder in a web app like the following:

```
listRef.listAll().then((res) => {
    // I get the list of items here
    res.items.forEach((imgRef) => {
        // 404 error
        imgRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            console.log(url);
            mapFile(url, imgRef.metadata);
        });
     });
 });
```

I successfully list **res.items** but when I try to use **getDownloadURL()** I get a 404 reference, I did notice that I get **folder/image** in the reference of the item and when I browse the file using the firebase storage console it browses the slash "/" encoded as %2F

my references are the following:

```
 const storageRef = firebase.app().storage('gs://some-name').ref();
 const listRef = storageRef.child(`${Id1}`);
```

when I save the image I use the following reference:

```
const imageRef = storageRef.child(`${Id1}/${this.file.name}`);
```

**Edit:**

**I'm getting the default bucket** as a response however I'm setting up the correct storage bucket endpoint in the storage reference, which is not the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it somehow a little bit hacky

since the method **listAll()** were returning the default bucket name I replaced the bucket name (without the gs//) with the **name** I needed.

```
imgRef.location.bucket = 'non-default-bucket-name';
imgRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => url); //<- worked
```